# How to get Process object of already running process?

Tags: c++-cli

I want a create a C++ program that can find an already running process and then redirect its Standard Output to my own stream for re-direction.  I can find countless examples on how to start a new process but I want to try and do something like:

```
Process^ proc = new Process();
proc->Attach("notepad.exe");
```

And then have control over the already running notepad.exe process.. Is this possible? If not then I guess I can find a way to start the process from within my application, however then my question would be how can I start a process and send command-line arguments to the process as if I were starting it up in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx). It will return an array of all the processes that match the name you give.

```
array<Process^>^ notepadProcesses = Process::GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

Comment: that worked, only thing is I don't think it will let me redirect output once the process has started running