# Attach to running program with powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-iot-core-10

I have a Raspberry Pi v2 running Windows 10 IoT and am trying to run a dotnet 2.0 console application on it.

I have a powershell script start it on startup, but then I do not get the console output from it. I was wondering if there was a way to attach to the running process with powershell on my computer, like you would to a docker container, to get the console output.

I do not want to run my program on my computer, and the Raspberry Pi is the only computer I want to leave on overnight to run the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you can't or don't want to re-start your Application

You are rather limited in this case, since, as stated in another [SE Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317573/get-already-running-windows-process-console-output-in-a-command-prompt-direct) by Harry Johnston:

> Windows does not provide any mechanism to retroactively give another
>   process a standard output handle if it was created without one.
>   (Besides, in most cases an application will check the standard output
>   handle only during startup.)

If you need to read something that already has been written to the Console, you are probably out of luck.
You should however be able to get any *future* output by attaching to the process with debugging tools.
In case of the [Visual Studio Remote Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx), this would even allow you to debug the execution of your Console Application, *provided you wrote it*.

An [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/624385/how-do-i-capture-the-command-line-output-of-an-already-running-application) on Superuser.com suggests that [StraceNT](http://intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=StraceNT) is also capable of read the output of a running Console Application. This will probably be your best bet if the running Application wasn't written by yourself.

### If the Application can be stopped and restarted

**Powershell Remoting** is probably the best way.

You would need to [enable Powershell Remoting](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) on your Raspberry Pi, and then you can use `enter-pssession [RaspberryPi-Hostname-or-IP]` in your local Powershell console to connect to your Raspberry Pi.

At that point you can just start your console application as if you were running it on your local machine and get all the console output you want.

No need to attach to anything.

Comment: That is a good idea, but my Raspberry pi is already running the program, so could I get the console output from the running process, even after I closed the powershell window that started the process.

Comment: Your answer is great, but I will probably use the text file one

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of your console app to a txt file in the current directory. If you run the console app from powershell you can do it like this:

```
.\[YOURAPP].exe | tee test.txt
```

And you can access the test.txt from [Windows file sharing](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/windowsfilesharing).